# Is there a way to see a fields variant relation in templates?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

To clarify; if I have a disabled variant, and I'm looping through categories (colors) on each product like `{% for variantColor in variantColors  %}...{% endfor %}` which makes it still show up in the list of colors.

Is there a way to, in that for loop, check if the variant it's connected to is enabled/disabled and then disregard, similar to `{% for variant in variants if variant.enabled %}`?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I solved this within the module I've built to handle product types with categories, but would be great to know how to do this in Twig as opposed to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you could filter the variants for the status `enabled` to output only the enabled variants of the product.

```
 {% set products = craft.products.all() %}
 {% for product in products %}
     {{ product.title }} <br>
     {% set variants = product.variants|filterByValue('enabled', "1") %}
     {%- for purchasable in variants -%}
          {{ purchasable.id }} - {{ purchasable.description }} - {{ purchasable.price }}<br>
     {%- endfor -%}
 {% endfor %}
```